# Storing Current date in database

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, oracle10g

I am having a column in my table of type `TIMESTAMP`.
In my servlet am writing the code to insert current date and time in this column like this :

```
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 Date date = new Date();
 String sendDate = dateFormat.format(date);
 ps.setString(4,sendDate);
```

But it throws an `Exception` that:

```
 java.sql.SQLException: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

What can be the reason?

Please help.

Comment: Why don't you let the database generate the date and use the `SYSDATE()` function?

Answer (score 3):

Why do you use `ps.setString` ?
You should use `ps.setDate`.

**EDIT**

```
Date dateNow = new java.sql.Date(System.CurrentTimeMillis())
ps.setDate(dateNow);
```

Better to use timestamp tough:

```
ps.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: And then how to get present system date?Could you please write it here?

Comment: and how to retrieve it back ?If say i want date and time in two different strings.?

Comment: to read it from database? you need to create a select qeury and user ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(s);

Comment: yeah i know this .But how to bring it in form of string.Am asking this

Comment: I dont fully understand.. you should get it as a date column, not string. rs.getDate(1)..

Comment: I need to store this date also in a variable while inserting it in table.How to do it ?

Comment: If you use 'Date' so you have datNow.if you mean the timestamp? use java.sql.Timestamp timpStamp =  new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()